# Why does my searchbar appear in the worng location?

Tags: html, css, layout, materialize

After clicking the searchbar white space which should appear on the navbar.

However, it appears in the wrong place when using Chrome:
[image: Chrome]

It looks properly on Firefox:
[image: Firefox]
(but then layout of site is looking weird, not like intended)

Here is my attempt so far:

```
<!-- Navbar.vue -->
<template>
  <nav class="light-blue lighten-1" role="navigation">
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <div class="row">
                <!-- Logo on the left -->
                <div class="col m2">
                    <a href="#" class="brand-logo">TabletopHaven</a>
                </div>
                
                <!-- Search bar in the center -->
                <div class="col m7">
                    <form>
                        <div class="input-field center-align">
                            <input id="search" type="search" required>
                            <label class="label-icon" for="search"><i class="material-icons">search</i></label>
                            <i class="material-icons">close</i>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

                <!-- Login button on the right -->
                <div class="col m3 right-align">
                    <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">Register/Login</a>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'MainNavbar',
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.nav-wrapper {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    width:100%;
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons');

</style>
```

Here is fiddle code so you can check it (it looks a little different):
https://jsfiddle.net/Lxbwv5yq/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to solve this.

Basically you need to change the height of searchbar because it is too big and it's overlapping to other containers